# return and exit from compactMap

Tags: swift

I am checking some dynamic texts with **Regex Rules**, using `switch` for each `index` of regex pattern `array`. everything is working fine but in the last `case` i want the map to stop mapping and do an early return! but seems like i can't `return` inside a map function! any better approach or solution ?

```
fileprivate func regexMatch(pattern regex: [String], in text: String) -> Dictionary<String, Any>
{
    do
    {
        for (index, string) in regex.enumerated()
        {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: string, options: .caseInsensitive)
            let results: [NSTextCheckingResult] = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSRange(text.startIndex..., in: text))

            _ = results.compactMap
            {
                /* If i put a guard check to see if result is filled 
                 * then return, works fine but iterates again for the next index and keeps returning till it’s over!
                */
                switch index
                {
                case 0:
                    // Does something
                case 1:
                    // Does something else
                case 2:
                    // Does the last thing
                    // If succeed finding the match! Just return or exit the map!
                    let carNames = String(Range($0.range, in: text).map { String(text[$0]) }!).lowercased()

                    for case let car as Car in carsList!
                    {
                        if spottedCarNamesInReceipt.contains(car.name!.lowercased())
                        {
                            result["car"] = car
                            return  // This does work though, but the map starts iterating again over the next index!
                        }
                    }

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return result

    } catch let error
    {
        print("Invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return [:]
    }
```

Comment: Never use a `map` or `compactMap` for its side effects (you are discarding its return value), use `forEach` instead or a regular `for-in` loop if you want to be able to do an early return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `return` statement `forEach` loop or any kind of `Maps`, exits only for the current call in the closure while `for...in` loop exits all the next subsequent calls as well. so `for...in` solves the problem if an early exit is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use compactMap if you don't use results. And there is no way to exit from compactMap. Use for in cycle.